# Typescript: save type when mutating accumulator inside Array.reduce

Tags: typescript, object, mutation

This function adds deeply nested property to object, taking string in format 'a.very.ddep.property' as argument.

```js
function nest<B extends obj, V = unknown>(
    target: B,
    structure: string,
    value: V,
) {
    const properties = structure.split('.');
    const result = target;
    properties.reduce((acc, property, i, arr) => {
        const isLastProperty = i === arr.length - 1;
        if (!(property in acc))
            acc[property] = isLastProperty ? value : {};
        return acc[property];
    }, target);
    return target;
}
```

It works fine in Javascript, but in Typescript I get an error `Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'B'` trying to assign `accum[property]`.
Normally I could avoid mutating `acc` by creating another object with intersection type, but using `reduce` suggests that I must mutate acc insude callback to get the final result.

`(accum as B & { [property: string]: obj | V })[property] = isLastProperty ? value : {};` doesn't work either, giving me error `type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'B & { [property: string]: obj | V;` }
What is the way, then?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do does not mesh very well with TypeScript because TypeScript is statically typed, but the resulting split `properties` array will be dynamic and likely only determinable at runtime.

It's still possible to do, but it's a bit verbose:

```
function nest<B extends object, V = unknown>(
    target: B,
    structure: string,
    value: V,
) {
    const properties = structure.split('.');
    const result = target;
    const lastProp = properties.pop();
    const lastObj = properties.reduce((acc, property) => {
        if (!(property in acc))
            acc[property] = {};
        const nestedVal = acc[property];
        if (!nestedVal || typeof nestedVal !== 'object') {
            throw new Error();
        }
        return nestedVal;
    }, target);
    lastObj[lastProp] = value;
    return target;
}
```

Important parts include:

- Add the final nested value after the end of the `reduce` so that the `reduce` callback can be consistently properly typed as `<object>`
- Throw an error inside the callback if the property doesn't exist, or isn't an object, to be type-safe
- Extract `acc[property]` into a standalone variable first so it can be narrowed (can't narrow `acc[property]` with `in` like that)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Нeah, Typescript requires slightly different way of thinking...

Your code still gives errors with strict checks enabled (`"Element implicitly has an 'any' type...'` at `acc[property]`") . This can be cured by changing `<B extends object>` to `<B extends Record<string, any>`, byt then it becomes `"Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'B'"`.

Also, the resulting type does not include added properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well it wasn't easy, but with Typescript 4 template literals I managed to make a type-safe version of this.

```
    type DeepType<T, S extends string> = T extends object
            ? S extends `${infer Key}.${infer NextKey}`
                ? Key extends keyof T
                    ? DeepType<T[Key], NextKey>
                    : false
                : S extends keyof T
                ? T[S]
                : never
            : T;
        
    type RecursiveKeyOf<TObj extends object> = {
            [TKey in keyof TObj & (string | number)]: RecursiveKeyOfHandleValue<
                TObj[TKey],
                `${TKey}`
            >;
        }[keyof TObj & (string | number)];
        type RecursiveKeyOfInner<TObj extends object> = {
            [TKey in keyof TObj & (string | number)]: RecursiveKeyOfHandleValue<
                TObj[TKey],
                RecursiveKeyOfAccess<TKey>
            >;
        }[keyof TObj & (string | number)];
        type RecursiveKeyOfHandleValue<
            TValue,
            Text extends string
        > = TValue extends object
            ? Text | `${Text}${RecursiveKeyOfInner<TValue>}`
            : Text;
        type RecursiveKeyOfAccess<TKey extends string | number> =
            | `['${TKey}']`
            | `.${TKey}`;
type obj = Record<string, any>;

export function addNestedProperty<
    B extends Record<string, any>,
    P extends string & RecursiveKeyOf<B>,
    V extends DeepType<B, P>
>(
    base: B,
    path: P,
    value: V,
    o: { overwrite: boolean } = { overwrite: true },
): B {
    const properties = path.split('.') as Array<string & keyof B>;
    const lastProperty = properties.pop();
    if (!lastProperty)
        throw new Error('path argument must contain at least one property');

    function isObject(arg: unknown): arg is object {
        return typeof arg === 'object' && arg !== null;
    }

    const lastObj = properties.reduce((acc, property) => {
        if (!(property in acc)) acc[property] = {} as any;
        else if (!isObject(acc) && !o.overwrite)
            throw new Error('you are trying to overwrite existing property');
        return acc[property];
    }, base);

    lastObj[lastProperty] = value;
    return base;
}
```